# Run a jQuery to every element of the same class return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found a piece of code in pure JS to apply an ellipsis in a text.

```
function dotify(element) {
    var limit = element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight;
    var dots = document.createElement('span');
    if (element['data-inner'])
        element.innerHTML = element['data-inner'];
    else
        element['data-inner'] = element.innerHTML;
    dots.appendChild(document.createTextNode('...'));
    element.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    element.appendChild(dots);
    while (dots.offsetTop + dots.offsetHeight > limit) {
        dots.previousSibling.data = dots.previousSibling.data
            .replace(/\W*\w+\W*$/, '')
    }
}
```

When I apply this code to one element, it works like a charm. However, when I use the `each()` function to apply it to every element with the same class, I have an undefined error.

```
jQuery(".product-description").each(function() {
    dotify(jQuery(this));
    onresize = function(){ setTimeout(function() { dotify(jQuery(this)); }, 100); };
});
```

The following works:

```
test = jQuery(".product-description")[0]
dotify(test);
onresize = function(){ setTimeout(function() { dotify(test); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a dom element reference to `dotify`, not a jQuery object reference.

```
jQuery(".product-description").each(function () {
    var el = this;
    dotify(el);
    onresize = function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            dotify(el);
        }, 100);
    };
});
```

Note: Not sure what is the purpose of `onresize` function in the code

Comment: The truth is that I am not sure either. However, your code works now. Thank you. I have one more question related with the code, but I should open a new one.

Comment: @Tasos it will be better to ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

`donotify` method accepts DOM object and you have passed jquery object in each function. passing dom object of current context(i.e. `this`) in each function will fix the problem:

```
jQuery(".product-description").each(function() {
  var current_descr = this;
  dotify(current_descr );
  onresize = function(){ setTimeout(function() { dotify(current_descr ); }, 100); };
});
```

Comment: Also, just to add,  `jQuery(".product-description")[0]` gives the DOM Node and not the `jQuery` object, that is why the code is working.